# How to create a footer with a logo on the left

Tags: html, css, footer

For a few days I've been trying to create a footer that is consistent with the style of my site, which is itself in the process of being created but already has a defined style

I have an image to illustrate the footer "of my dreams" :p
And I would like to know how I can create it ? I thought of creating divs containing `<p>` and `<a>` the `<p>` for the titles and the `<a>` to contain the different links

Here is an image of what I would like to have on my site: https://prnt.sc/13kr8kt

Would anyone know how to explain me the right way? Because I tried but unfortunately impossible to succeed... I would like to understand my mistakes thanks in advance!

Here is my code :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, .87);
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 100%;
}

.circuit {
  background-image: url(img/background.svg);
  background-color: rgba(62, 62, 62, 1);
  padding: 192px 0 112px;
}

.dark {
  background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);
  padding: 192px 16px;
}

.topbar {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.topbar nav {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.middle {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.topbar nav a {
  color: #9F9F9F;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.topbar nav a:hover,
.topbar nav a.active {
  color: #000;
}

.header-logo {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 25vh;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.footer {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgb(9, 9, 9);
  padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Poseidon | The Perfect Discord Bot</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="img/favicon.svg">

  <header class="topbar">
    <a href="#"><img class="header-logo" src="img/logo.svg" alt="Kurium Logo" href="index.html"></a>
    <nav>
      <div class="middle">
        <a href="invite.html">Invite</a>
        <a href="commands.html">Commands</a>
        <a href="documentation.html">Documentation</a>
        <a href="support.html">Support</a>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <a href="/">Social 1</a>
        <a href="/">Social 2</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="circuit">
    <h1>The Perfect Discord Bot.</h1>
    <h2>Poseidon is the only Discord bot you'll ever need!</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="dark">
    <h1>The Perfect Discord Bot.</h1>
    <h2>Poseidon is the only Discord bot you'll ever need!</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="dark">
    <h1>The Perfect Discord Bot.</h1>
    <h2>Poseidon is the only Discord bot you'll ever need!</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="dark">
    <h1>The Perfect Discord Bot.</h1>
    <h2>Poseidon is the only Discord bot you'll ever need!</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="circuit">
    <h1>The Perfect Discord Bot.</h1>
    <h2>Poseidon is the only Discord bot you'll ever need!</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <footer>
      Copyright
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use a grid layout... one row, four columns, flex your children with column direction.

Comment: You have an invalid HTML markup. `<header>` is not allowed to be part of the `<head>` element. It has to be part of the `<body>` element. Everything that should be displayed on the screen belongs into the `<body>`. The `<head>` element is for meta data such as title, links to css and scripts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a grid layout with flex on the logo element. using grid-layout you can express how wide you want the columns to be using `grid-template-columns:` then call the grid-area on each selector with in the grid parent. You may need to tweak a bit to your liking depending on what view ports you are going for.

Use flex on child items you wish to align in a row. Simple Ul/li for links...

```css
/* for display purposes in this snippit only adding margin and padding 
   to your body may have a negatrive affect on your display in your browser */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/**/

#footer {
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 0.9fr 0.7fr 0.2fr 1.2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1.9fr 0.1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "logo product resource resource business"   
  "social social . design design";
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 2%;
  font-size: .9em;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

#footer li a {
  color: #065299;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  grid-area: logo;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-top: .5rem;
}

.img {
  padding-top: .5rem;
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
}

.logo h4 {
  line-height: 1rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.copy {
  padding-top: .3rem;
  font-size: .7em;
  color: #7d8287;
}

.product {
  grid-area: product;
}

.resource {
  grid-area: resource;
}

.business {
  grid-area: business;
}

.social { 
  grid-area: social;
  padding-left: .3rem;
  padding-bottom: .3rem; 
  font-size: .6em;
  display: flex;
}

.design {
  grid-area: design;
  font-size: .6em;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: .3rem;
  padding-bottom: .3rem;
}

.icons {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  padding-left: .3rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="flex">
      <img class="img" src="https://thumb9.shutterstock.com/image-photo/redirected-150nw-795281602.jpg">
      <h4>My Company</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="copy">&#169; Poseidon Bot 2012 - All Rights Reserved</div>
  </div>
  <ul class="product">
    <li><b>Product</b></li>
    <li><a href="#">Invite</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Commands</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Premium</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="resources">
    <li><b>Resources</b></li>
    <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Provacy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Refunds</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="business">
    <li><b>Business</b></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="design">
    designed with ❤ by <span style="color: #065299;">My Discord ID</span>
  </div>  
  <div class="social">
    <img class="icons" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/mono-general-3/128/twitter-icon.png">
    <img class="icons" src="https://www.stackbuilders.com/assets/img/github-icon-hover.png">
    <img class="icons" style="filter: invert(100%)" src="https://www.iconninja.com/files/625/765/244/social-media-stackoverflow-icon.png">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: note the circled items in the picture, they take up two different wide columns to make up their full width. Resource is 0.2 + 0.7 which = 0.9fr, where design is 0.2 + 1.2 which is = 1.4fr, furthermore this allow us to skew the bottom row column by starting its left side at the preceding column which is 0.2fr to the left of resources right side.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but my design is out of line with the footer, what is the reason? Can I use this method to add what I need (especially what is missing): https://prnt.sc/13kv7hm 
The things that are wrong : https://prnt.sc/13kv8u6 
-> https://prnt.sc/13kv9np how to fix these different problems please ?

Comment: I can't increase the size of the black background, I'd like the footer to be bigger but I can't do padding: 100px or height: 100px

Comment: OK on the grid element, remove the `width: 100vw;` see if that fixes the partial section on the side and scrolling issue.

Comment: Yes the problem is solved for that but how to enlarge the black area please? And can I add the things that are missing especially the "Design by" I can add a <p>?

Comment: Then there is also the padding of Business : https://prnt.sc/13kw81x which is not the same as : Resources & Product : https://prnt.sc/13kw8fs

Comment: Okay, I have edited the code and added a new column section to accommodate the bottom designed by text.

Comment: Thanks it works but I still have the problem to enlarge my footer & then I have this result now: https://prnt.sc/13kwu7s Do you know how to do it please? I would really like my design to match this one: https://prnt.sc/13kr8kt

Comment: How are you placing the footer on the bottom of the page? Position fixed, bottom: 0? Have you looked at the browser inspector to note what is going on with the section that is sitting off the bottom of the fold?

Comment: Also, try adding more height to the footer, maybe `30%` and increasing the line-height or top padding on the `li` elements.

Comment: Are you talking about the #footer? Because nothing is defined in fixed position And I used the console to see if the titles were symmetrical and I noticed that the padding was different on Business that's all (I don't know if that answers your question)

Comment: Well how are you positioning your footer element to the bottom of your page? You should be able to open your browser inspector tool and then highlight the footer element in the inspector and look at the layout style to see if there is some kind of extra margin being added somewhere...

Comment: That's exactly what I'm telling you Business has a bigger padding than the other titles

Comment: Also make sure to note the new code i placed in there to add both your design tag and social media icons...

Comment: my code : https://bin.readthedocs.fr/rtexta.txt (html) & css : https://bin.readthedocs.fr/etyrin.txt

Comment: Yes i see it i think its good no what you think now?? https://bin.readthedocs.fr/rtexta.txt (html) & css : https://bin.readthedocs.fr/etyrin.txt

Comment: It does not look like you added the last code edit I made. I added a bottom row and extra column to the grid layout to accommodate the two bottom elements, social media and design... But if you like it, glad I was able to help out!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what you're talking about because I have this: 
HTML : https://bin.readthedocs.fr/anklia.txt
CSS : https://bin.readthedocs.fr/pupime.txt
And yes you helped me a lot, I thank you very much thanks to you I was able to understand many mistakes and it seems to me rather responsive which is perfect
I still have some problems to solve, especially the icons: https://prnt.sc/13kxqoa

Comment: For the icons I think it comes from the areas because: https://prnt.sc/13ky56c = https://prnt.sc/13ky5mj
and https://prnt.sc/13ky6qj = https://prnt.sc/13ky6yr

Comment: Yea you need to add the second row to the grid-template areas, there is also a column that is added as well, two of the columns take up two fractions of the template for columns... See my earlier edit and uploaded photo showing the new `grid-template-areas` layout....

Comment: Sorry but I have to add one by one the elements because I made modifications I would not like to lose them and by adding: "social social . design design"; it made me this: https://prnt.sc/13l1wkb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233077/discussion-between-kalypsotek-and-dale-landry).

Comment: You can talk in discussion chat  please?